# Semi colon expected?

Tags: java

It is telling my that a semi colon is expected in between the second "%lf" and the comma before the "x". Here is the code segment:

```
 public String toString() {
        return "%lf, %lf", x, y; 
    }
```

I am trying to return the string "(X, Y)"

Any ideas?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comma-separated variables cannot be recognized as a valid `Strings` in Java.

It appears you are using format specifiers similar to those found in `C/C++`'s [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) function.

Assuming that `x` and `y` are valid floating point values you can use

```
return String.format("%f, %f", x, y);
```

to format the output `String`

Read: [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with format strings, is `%lf` a valid element thereof?

Comment: No its not should be just `%f`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you are trying to do. You can't return multiple values as the method is declared `String`. Try as follows:

```
return "%lf, %lf"+x+y;
```

for a literal contatenation.

```
return String.format("%f, %f", x, y);
```

will use a format string.

Answer (score 2):

```
return "%lf, %lf", x, y;
```

is not a `String`

```
return "%lf, %lf, x, y";
```

or

```
return "%lf, %lf" + x + y;
```

is a String.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to access multiple values, just use two different functions to return the values. if you want to return both values as a single string, use concatenation.